# alamkanak Week-view : Same Event name is apprearing 3 times in single row

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have this problem, the events appear 3 times in one row 
and when i use this method doesn't appear

```
private List<WeekViewEvent> getEventsForMonth(int year, int month) {
        List<WeekViewEvent> tempList = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
        for (WeekViewEvent weekViewEvent : events) {
           if (weekViewEvent.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MONTH) == month && weekViewEvent.getStartTime().get(Calendar.YEAR) ==
                    year) {
                tempList.add(weekViewEvent);
           }
        }

        return tempList;
    }
```

I use it here

```
 MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener mMonthChangeListener = new MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {

        return getEventsForMonth(newYear,newMonth);
            //return events; (if I use this the events appear 3 time)
        }
    };
```

Well I know that the "onMonthChange" is called 3 time and I tried to clear the tempList before i use it but it still the same problem 
I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808769/android-week-view-alamkanak-library-triplicates-event-names) but it doesn't work

NB :  The method "getEventsForMonth" it worked until yesterday, and  I didn't change anything on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I resolved the problem using newMonth-1 in onMonthChange
because after showing the value of month from the calendar I found that for example January have the value 0 and +1 for each next month 
but newMonth in onChangeMonth give the real value of the month for example January = 1

> here is the new onChangeMonth

```
public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
            int month = newMonth-1;
        return getEventsForMonth(newYear,month);// I tried to use newMonth-1 directly here but it dosen't work i don't know why but it doesn't matter
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this function run 3 times, so you need to do a matching date, where it only returns the event for that particular month.